# How to retrieve actual row inserted into SQL Server?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, database, pyodbc

i wanted to create a function that can insert records into a table,  would be cool to print back the created record columns to know that it worked, since that information will be use later on for the next query.

following the tutorial from

https://cppsecrets.com/users/1173109101103104971091051161169710849545464103109971051084699111109/Python-SQL-Server-insert-record-into-table-and-get-inserted-ID.php

```
def insert_query(cursor, query):
    cursor.execute(query)
    cursor.commit()
    cursor.execute("SELECT @@IDENTITY AS ID;")
    all1 = cursor.fetchall()
    print(all1)
```

my query:

```
insert into my_table values (102,'testing_stuff' , 3,'Y')
```

works at some degree since i get in return

```
[(Decimal('113'), )]
```

in fact thats the created key, is there a way where i can get all the columns?  i guess has something to do with the part

any tips guys?
thanks.

```
"SELECT @@IDENTITY AS ID;"
```

Comment: Any basic SQL tutorial should cover the `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can put an OUTPUT clause in your INSERT statement to return the values inserted. For the test table ...

```sql
CREATE TABLE #party (
    guest_id int identity primary key,
    guest_name nvarchar(50) not null,
    beverage nvarchar(50) default N'water'
);
```

... if you just insert the one mandatory column you'll get a result set that shows the identity and default values that were inserted ...

```
1> INSERT INTO #party (guest_name)
2> OUTPUT INSERTED.guest_id, INSERTED.guest_name, INSERTED.beverage
3> VALUES (N'Edith');
4> go
guest_id    guest_name beverage
----------- ---------- --------
          1 Edith      water

(1 rows affected)
```

... but if you insert values into some other (optional) columns they will be returned, too

```
1> INSERT INTO #party (guest_name, beverage)
2> OUTPUT INSERTED.guest_id, INSERTED.guest_name, INSERTED.beverage
3> VALUES (N'Gord', N'bourbon');
4> go
guest_id    guest_name beverage
----------- ---------- --------
          2 Gord       bourbon

(1 rows affected)
```